# Apache CustomLog for WSGI server is not filtered by LogLevel

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, mod-wsgi, loglevel

I have a [WSGI server which is served by an Apache proxy](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57851/apache-redirect-url-of-internal-wsgi-server). I would like to have a log file dedicated to that server, so I added the following to the `VirtualHost` declaration:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" wsgi_server
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wsgi_server.log wsgi_server
LogLevel crit
```

After Apache restarts, I still see some low-level (info? debug?) Log messages in `wsgi_server.log`:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2014:12:16:07 +0000] "GET /image/2014.02.24.10.33.41.540801-4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 33895
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2014:12:16:07 +0000] "GET /image/2014.02.24.10.35.47.666532-3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6665
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2014:12:16:07 +0000] "GET /image/2014.02.24.10.18.20.501241-9999.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 93619
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2014:12:16:07 +0000] "GET /image/2014.02.24.10.17.54.087584-9999.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 28088
...
```

How do I exclude all Log message below `crit` from my WSGI custom log, and keep only the printouts from the Python WSGI module?

Answer (score 1):

The [LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel) directive controls the verbosity of the [ErrorLog](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errorlog). That looks like an [access log](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog) to me so your `LogLevel crit` won't have any effect on it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to configure my log to be an access log?

Comment: @AdamMatan: Erm it already is an access log. I don't think that there is much in the way of tuning the verbosity of the access log it's all or nothing so if you don't want it then don't define a CustomLog.